# Referencing My.Settings across projects?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I've been poking around in some projects written by one of our contractors, and he seems to be storing a lot of settings in the main "app.config" file for the application, using, for example:

```
<add key="SomeClass/SomeValue" value="False"/>
```

And then referencing the key value in the "SomeClass" class in "SomeProjectLibrary" using

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SomeClass/SomeValue")
```

While this *works*, I guess, it also pretty much sucks. I was wondering if anyone knew of some more elegant way of creating variables in the "app.config" file, which could then be used across various applications within a Solution?

Hopefully I'm just missing something blindingly obvious.

Comment: What isn't elegant about that?  Is it the key name?  Or is it that they're all lumped into one config file?

Comment: It's just that the app.config file is a member of the final Windows Forms project, and the "SomeLibraryProject" relies on the existence of those keys in the app.config file of the running project. That part seems messy to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could make a utility class that you will us for reading your config file. If you put this class in a separate project (say, a utilities project) then you could reference this project from all your other projects. For example:

```
Public NotInheritable Class ConfigReader
    Private Shared reader As New AppSettingsReader()

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property SomeValue() As String
        Get
            Return reader.GetValue("SomeClass/SomeValue", GetType(String)).ToString()
        End Get
    End Property

//etc..
```

Usage:

```
string someValue = ConfigReader.SomeValue
```

Comment: I like that. It kind of screams "bloat", but from the look of some of these app.config files, so does the other method, so I'm not really losing anything. Cheers.